# Is this a serious question, or trolling?

Tags: discussion, trolling

[Is there a diplomatic way to explain to a manager that they're pushing without any leverage?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54491/is-there-a-diplomatic-way-to-explain-to-a-manager-that-theyre-pushing-without-a)

I struggled with deciding if this is a serious question, or was just trolling. I don't like to feed the trolls, and I try to assume positive intent on most questions.

In the end I answered it, but I'm having a hard time believing the OP actually feels this way.

Am I alone in feeling conflicted?

Comment: What makes you think it's a troll? OP seems to have seriously misguided notions on suitable workplace behaviour but we've had our share of those.

Comment: It's basically this question, right? Except with more "I'm awesome! Why wont' my manager bow down and respect me?" http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/18119/2322

Comment: You're not alone, Joe. You'll notice my opening statement in my answer said I wasn't going to answer. If it's trolling, I fed the troll :)

Comment: @enderland - yup, very similar.

Comment: @Lilienthal - I guess it's because in my 45 years of work I never personally encountered a software engineer with quite this high a level of "entitlement". Maybe I've lived a sheltered life...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have _definitely_ encountered them in my 20 years in this industry :)  They're the ones that you quietly move on because they don't have the capacity to think beyond their own little wants and needs rather than the bigger picture.

Comment: I've met people who think this way, and I'm very new (8j) to the working world... It just reads like he put what he wanted to do in the question as if he actually did it. Harmless all-be-it childish fantasizing.

Answer (score -7):

At this point, the Be Nice policy clearly states to assume good intent.

Comment: He says he tries to do so.  That doesn't mean the assumption is always correct.  Asking for input on whether to help or walk away, as the OP does here, seems fine to me.